# glutWarpPointer() does nothing in my program

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut, voxel

I have been trying to create a simple voxel game with Glut, and everything is working great except for 'glutWarpPointer()' that does nothing at all, the cursor is not altered in any way and I have no idea why.
I've tried with WSL on windows 11 (freeglut vers. 2.8.1-6), macos big sur (freeglut vers. 3.4.0) and catalina and it does not work anywhere.

```
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

int     width = 0, height = 0;

void    display()
{
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}

void    idle()
{
    glutWarpPointer(width / 2, height / 2);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int     main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    width = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH);
    height = glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("42");
    glutFullScreen();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

It does work with WSL on windows 10 (freeglut vers. 2.8.1-3) with Xming in full screen mode, but i would like to be able to use it everywhere

Comment: What does [`SetCursorPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos) return in [`fgPlatformWarpPointer()`](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut/blob/v3.4.0/src/mswin/fg_cursor_mswin.c#L119-L128)?  Which version of FreeGLUT are you using?  Also, expand that code block out into a proper [mcve]: there's no telling what sins `ft_vox.hpp` may be committing.

Comment: Sorry about the code format, I've edited accordingly. I have tested it on multiple freeGlut versions, specified in the edit. I forgot to mention that I use WSL and those functions seem to be windows specific, therefore I cannot test SetCursorPos().

Comment: "4.2 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5", "3.1 Mesa 20.0.8", and "3.1 Mesa 20.0.8" look like OpenGL versions, not FreeGLUT versions (most recent FreeGLUT release is [`v3.4.0`](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut/releases/tag/v3.4.0)).

Comment: Yes my bad, i've modified it.